# How do I reduce the vertical space between list items in an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I've got a very simple html unordered list:

```
<ul>
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

The problem is that the default styling for such a list in firefox leaves a lot of space between each list item - about the same as between paragraphs in a `<p>` tag.  My google-fu is proving uncharacteristically useless today - how do I reduce that vertical space?  I assume there's a css element I can apply to the `<ul>` tag, but I can't seem to find anything.

(This is going in the side navigation element of a page so it needs to be as compact as possible.)

Comment: If inside a <pre> tag, you should use white-space: normal

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Further to all the other answers, it might be worth setting `line-height: 1em;` to reduce the leading space of each line. Of course, the `padding-top`, `padding-bottom`, `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` are all the most-likely culprits.

Comment: Aha!  It was an inherited line-height value that was causing my problems.  Thanks, ricebowl!

Comment: Don't use `padding` because it also changes the distance between the list and the texts above and below the list, while `margin` doesn't change it if the value is less than `1em` as you can see here https://i.imgur.com/aB690Gb.gif

Comment: For anyone seeing this solution, keep in mind that the value of `line-height` could be less than 1 in order to work. PS you might not need padding and margin at all

Answer (score 6):

Reduce or eliminate the top and bottom margins and paddings. E.g:

```
li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0.2em;
}
```

PS: Since you are using Firefox, try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). When you click on elements in the HTML tree in Firebug, it will highlight the element on the page itself. It colors the content, margin and padding separately so you can see exactly how margins and paddings affect your layout.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `margin` and `padding` CSS properties to whatever sizes you'd like. For maximum compactness, use:

```
ul, li { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

None of those worked for me.

I had an unsorted list with a fixed height and width that had to be exactly the sum of the list elements with it's paddings and/or margins. Actually 9 list elements that had to be put in a square 3 x 3.

What worked for me is to put

```
li{
    height: 144px;
    width: 144px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the `top-margin`, `bottom-margin` and padding of the `<li>` element as such:

```
li { margin: 1em 3em; padding: 0.2em; }
```

Answer (score 2):

The properties margin and padding are the correct approach.

I want to add the advice to reset your complete css with a predefined reset-css-file, like this one by Eric Meyer: [Link](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/index.html)

After this you have the option to control your styles more specified.

Answer (score -1):

```css
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
ul li {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Always works!

Answer (score -2):

I experienced this issue

> [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). When you click on elements in the HTML tree in Firebug, it
>   will highlight the element on the page itself. It colors the content, margin and padding > separately so you can see exactly how margins and paddings affect your layout.

Firebug showed no padding or margin.

When I changed the display property, the gap disappeared.

```
li { 
display: inline-block;
}
```

Produced a gap, however:

```
li { 
display: block;
}
```

did not.

Comment: issue with this one is that you loose icon ahead of each element